# A Euclidean-like property for partially-ordered magmas

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, order-theory

Let $\mathbf{X} = (X,+,\leq)$ be a partially ordered magma, i.e. $(X,+)$ is a [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)#Definition) (written additively), and $\leq$ is a partial order on $X$ satisfying: for every $x,y,z \in X$ such that $x \leq y$, $x+z \leq y+z$ and $z+x \leq z+y$.

Is there a name for the following property of $\mathbf{X}$, which is reminiscent of the property defining a [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain#Definition)?

> For every $a, b \in X$ there exist $q, r \in X$ such that $a = q + r$  and $r \leq b$. Moreover, the set of such $r$'s has a maximal element.

If there's a name for the property described in just the first of these two sentences, I'll be interested to know it too.

Comment: I don't have an answer to the main question, but I think the second condition would be better phrased as "Moreover, the set of such $q$ has a maximal element [i.e ...]"?

Comment: @Christopher: OK, I've rephrased.

Comment: Are you **missing** a $b$ in the formulation? Otherwise the formulae is trivial in the case that "+" has a unit "0" which is also a least element: Indeed then given any $a$ and $b$ we simply take $r, q := a, 0$ and the constraints are satisfied ;-)

(( Anyhow, the name *Euclidean magma* sounds fine. ))